# How to mix AND and OR operators in Django query?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I a Django beginner, I figured out how to dynamically create a model query but I'm stuck at some point when I'm tring to mix `AND` and `OR` operators:

I have a list of fields (contact_name, company, position, country), these fields might contain more than one keyword (separated by comma ',')

So if I search for these company names "imtech, ABC, FooBar" I get the right result with the code I have below, because it always uses the `|` (OR) operator.

But what if I want to restrict the search for entries with company field as "imtech, ABC, FooBar" AND position field as "Account Manager" only?

I know I have to put the `&` operator at the end of each loop of fields but I haven't succeded doing so, so here is my code, please help me!!!

```
search_fields = {'contact_name', 'company', 'position', 'country'}
search_fields_values = {}
qs_params = None

for field in search_fields:
    search_fields_values[field] = self.request.GET.get(field, None)
    if search_fields_values[field]:
        search_fields_values[field] = search_fields_values[field].split(',')

        for part in search_fields_values[field]:
            q = Q(**{field: part})
            qs_params = qs_params | q if qs_params else q

qs = qs.filter(qs_params)
```

Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood your question correctly.

Here's what should work in theory (haven't tested it though):

```
import operator

...

search_fields = {'contact_name', 'company', 'position', 'country'}

conditions = []
for name in search_fields:
    value = self.request.GET.get(name, None)
    if value:
        conditions.append(Q(**{name + "__in": value.split(',')}))

qs = qs.filter(reduce(operator.and_, conditions))
```

So, two ideas came into my mind:

- use `__in` instead of several ORs
- collect these `in` queries for each search field and then join them with AND

Hope that helps.

Comment: You're my man alecxe! Thanks a lot, it was exactly what I was looking for.